# Calling puppeteer from rest api

Tags: rest, api, puppeteer

Is the appropriate way to call puppeteer from a rest endpoint?

Route.js

```
const express = require('express');

const PuppeteerController = require('../controllers/puppetter');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/getPath', PuppeteerController.getPage);
```

---

Controller.js

```
async getPage(req, res) {
   try {
    let resp = await pageScanner.getPageContent(url);
    return res.status(200).send(resp);
   }
   catch(e) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        error: 'not-found'
      });
   }
}
```

---

Scanner.js

```
async getPageContent(url) {
   try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
          '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
          '--disable-gpu'
        ]
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
      await page.goto(url);
      await page.waitFor(1000);
      const pageContent = await page.content();
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
      return pageContent;
   } catch(e) {
     return 'No good'
   }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? I'm concerned on performance in case I have multiple hits to this endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that. I recommend to use a pool of puppeteer instances to limit the number of parallel executions. As you already noticed, otherwise you might have 10 open browsers in the case of 10 requests coming in at roughly the same time.

Check out the library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which supports your use case.

**Code Sample**

I took the code from the example ["Minimal screenshot server with express"](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/master/examples/express-screenshot.js) from the docs and adapted it to your use case. The code creates a cluster with multiple browsers (how many parallel instances you can use, depends on the CPU/memory/throughput of your machine) and spawns a express server to handle the incoming requests. The crawled URL is given by the parameter `?url=...`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_BROWSER,
        maxConcurrency: 4,
    });

    // setup the function to be executed for each request
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto('http://' + url);
        // ...
        return await page.content();
    });

    // setup server
    app.get('/', async function (req, res) { // expects URL to be given by ?url=...
        try {
            // run the task function for the URL
            const resp = await cluster.execute(req.query.url);
            // respond with the result
            res.status(200).send(resp);
        } catch (err) {
            // catch error
            res.end('Error: ' + err.message);
        }
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Server listening on port 3000.');
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, could you take a look at my follow up here when you get a chance? https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/issues/206